# manjaro/arch-linux: Installing base-devel breaks installation

Tags: linux, manjaro, libcrypto, libssl, pacman-package-manager

quick little disclaimer: I'm only somewhat experienced using linux.

On my system (manjaro kde-plasma) I installed base-devel.
After that, I had errors with missing sudoers.so, libcrypto.so and libssl.so. I tried to solve it and finally gave up (thus no more specific information about that installation). I freshly installed manjaro/i3. I connected to local network and installed base-devel (second thing I did). Same problem again.
When I try to "sudo" something, I get:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: unable to load /usr/lib/sudoers.so: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
sudo: fatal error, uable to load plugins
```

When I try to do something with pacman, I get:

```
pacman: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The same happens with reboot and shutdown as far as I can tell. It does not happen with shell commands like cd, chmod, chown or touch. Also, it does not happen with executables  like vim or sth.
Restarting the laptop does not help, in fact it completely stops working (during boot, same as last time) and I get:
[image: error message I get during boot]

Sorry for the image, but I cand copy the text since the computer won't boot.
Basically it says a something similar to:

```
/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempt to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
(...)
Call Trace:
  <TASK>
  dump_stack_lvl(...)
  panic(...)
  do_exit.cold(...)
  ? do_writev(...)
  do_group_exit(...)
  __x64_syscall_64(...)
  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode(...)
  ? do_syscall_64(...)
  ? do_syscall_64(...)
  ? exc_page_fault(...)
  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe(...)
RIP: (some hex)
Code: (some numbers)
(...)
  </TASK>
Kernel Offset: (some hex) from (some hex) (relocation range: hex-hex)
--- [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempt to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00 ] ---
```

Does anybody know what I can do, or at least what the actual problem is (explained for a dummy like me)?
Until then, I will simply not install base-devel (which is kind of a problem, since I'm a software-developer and this is my work-laptop...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did a partial upgrade. Download pacman-static, and do a full upgrade. `what the actual problem is` You updated pacman, but not the libraries that pacman depends on. Now it can't find the libraries, so it can't start.

Comment: Partial updates are never supported. Always `pacman -Syu` before installing any new package.  If a keyring update is needed, update the keyring first doing  `pacman -Sy --needed archlinux-keyring && pacman -Su`

Comment: thanks, i will try that on a different computer later this week!